# VS2010 Database Project Doesn't Properly Rename Columns

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

The more I use the DB Project, the less useful I find it.  I'm trying to use this project type to manage my db schema and be able to use it to generate differences for test/production schema updates.

Right now I'm stuck trying to rename a column.  I am using the object refactor tool, which updates the refactorlog, but that log seems to have no impact on the deployment of the sql file.  Every time I deploy or diff it generates the sql as a column drop and add which purges all the existing data.  You'd think the schema diff tool would have an option to map 2 columns as a rename, but that feature is conveniently missing.

Also, the Always re-create database option doesn't appear to do anything.  Regardless of the state of this checkbox, my deployed sql is exactly the same.  Which means each time I run it my database is re-created, which is contrary to what the document is telling me for unchecking this to run updates.

If the db project can't do a simple rename, then it's pretty much useless since I can't trust it to render the proper update sql (if and when I figure out how to prevent it from re-creating my database).

At this point I'm about to punt and just manage everything by hand, which I would prefer not to do, because contrary to my "useless" statement, the VS DB tools do some nice things, but 90% of the way there isn't good enough.

Has anyone else had experience dealing with these issues with a VS2010 DB Project who can talk me off the ledge?

Answer (score 2):

VS 2010 Schema Compare does not use the refactor log. That is used only when doing a project deployment. Here is a definitive statement to that effect from the product manager:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/fd2c3d02-8792-4d58-b1cb-0c804a1142de